# How to disable on-screen keyboard from popping up when TextField is tapped in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an input Text Field and I want to disable the on-screen keyboard for all the time. How can I achieve this in SwiftUI?

```
TextField("Input Amount", text: $inputAmount)
    .font(.largeTitle)
```

Comment: Then use just Text instead.

Comment: Yes. I also thought that. BTW, thanks.